# DELPHI: Store a some data in a shared memory to have an access from several apps

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-8, windows-7, delphi-xe3

**Problem defitintion**
I have two applications: *First* and *Second*. The *First* is mine, the *Second* is developed by the outsource.

1) At a certain time I need to send a message from the *First* app to the *Second*, to make *Second* one visible and maximized, after it has been minimized.

2) In order to do the (1) step, *Second* app should store its handle somewhere in a shared memory, which could be accessed by the name or by whatever it might be (like mutexes do).

**Question**

So, what is the better option to store data (a handle) in an operating memory?

Comment: Mutexes are mutual exclusion kernel objects. They are not used to store handles.

Comment: Why not? And what would be a descision?

Comment: Why not? Well, they don't store anything. They are for mutual exclusion. I must say that I don't really understand what you are asking at all. It's very broad and imprecise.

Comment: Well, I don't understand too, since I was asked to find out if there is any possibility to store a handle to Second App in a shared memory, and read that point from the First App (like Apps can access mutex by its name and which would be destroyed after no more applications points to it). And second question - can I still send a message from First to Second App to maximize and bring on top the last one. That's all.

Comment: We like one question at a time. I don't really want to write an answer to both different questions. Each one on its own is not too bad. And probably are both duplicates. I suggest that you ask one question at a time.

Comment: Should I still ask here or reboot?

Comment: If I were you I'd edit this question to be one single question. And then I for one will try to help.

Comment: Did it! So I hope now it's more readable and clear. Fire! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store this information in a shared place, then you would typically use shared memory. In Windows terms that's a file mapping object. Create one by calling `CreateFileMapping`. These are kernel objects and so can be named in the kernel namespace.

File mappings are not a whole lot of fun to work with, so you might like to find an easier solution. Give your application's main form a unique class name. For instance you might name the form's class `TMyCompanyNameMyProductNameMainForm`. Then call `FindWindow` passing that class name to find an existing application window.

Comment: What if I can't force the other developer to call this window class with such a name, but I can ask him to store its handle. So CreateFileMapping is the best solution in this case?

Comment: I'd probably still try to avoid a file mapping if you can. You could use other ways to make your window more recognisable. Use the window class name and the window text. That would be the caption of your main form which I presume includes the program name. But if you can't bring yourself to do that then a file mapping will do the job.

Comment: Well, I repeat - class names and window text - is totally in the "hands" of outsource developers and I can't influence on them much. But does file mapping acts like mutexes? I mean - do they destroy automatically if the program halts?

Comment: You probably don't need to influence them. You just need to make a determination as to whether or not you can reliably identify the main window based on its caption and name. File mappings are kernel objects. When all handles to the kernel object are closed, the kernel object is destroyed.

Comment: I understands. Thanks. I suppose that I can identify the main window. But I think the better solution is about File mappings. I think there is also possible to store some cross-app data. That would be the answer.

Comment: So feel free to use file mappings. I did say that in the answer.